# Cell array output is Slow in MEX

Tags: c++, performance, matlab, mex

I Have observed the following wierd problem pertaining to cell arrays. I am currently using Matlab R2013a. Consider the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

#include <mex.h>
#undef printf       // to undo redefinition of printf by mex.h
#include <matrix.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray **plhs, int nrhs, mxArray **prhs) {

    if (nrhs != 0) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("CellArray:InvalidInput", "There are too many input arguments required no of input args = 0");
    }
    if (nlhs != 1) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("CellArray:InvalidOutput", "Incorrect number of output arguments required no of output args = 1");
    }

    int CellArrSize = 50820;   // Number is prime
    int CellContentSizeCurr = 1;
    int CurrentCell = 732;

    mwSize CellArrayDims[] = { CellArrSize, 1 };
    std::vector<int *> IntArrayofArrays(CellArrSize, nullptr);
    std::vector<int> CellContentSize(CellArrSize);

    plhs[0] = mxCreateCellArray(2, CellArrayDims);

    // Filling the Array of Arrays with the content to output
    // into the cell array
    for (int i = 0; i < CellArrSize; ++i) {
        CellContentSizeCurr = (CellContentSizeCurr * 398) % 431; // 431 is primes 
        #ifdef IS_CONTIG
            CurrentCell = i;
        #else
            CurrentCell = ((CurrentCell + 1) * 732) % 50821 - 1;
        #endif
        IntArrayofArrays[CurrentCell] = reinterpret_cast<int *>(mxCalloc(CellContentSizeCurr, sizeof(int)));
        for (int j = 0; j < CellContentSizeCurr; ++j) {
            IntArrayofArrays[CurrentCell][j] = i * CellContentSizeCurr + j;
        }
        CellContentSize[CurrentCell] = CellContentSizeCurr;
    }

    // Performing output of the Array of Array into Cell array
    // (along with profiling code)
    int TimeTakeninus = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < CellArrSize; ++i) {
        mxArray * tempmxArray;
        mwSize mxArrayDims[] = { 0,0 };
        tempmxArray = mxCreateNumericArray(2, mxArrayDims, mxINT32_CLASS, mxREAL);
        mxSetM(tempmxArray, CellContentSize[i]);
        mxSetN(tempmxArray, 1);

        auto TimeBeg = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        mxSetData(tempmxArray, IntArrayofArrays[i]);
        auto TimeEnd = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        TimeTakeninus += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(TimeEnd - TimeBeg).count();
        mxSetCell(plhs[0], i, tempmxArray);
    }

    mexPrintf("The time taken to perform output = %d ms\n", TimeTakeninus / 1000);
    mexEvalString("drawnow");
}
```

There is an option (define) `IS_CONTIG` which basically decides if the memory in successive Arrays in 
IntArrayofArrays` is allocated contiguously or not. The numbers above are chosen so that even in the
discontiguous case, all cell indices from 0..to Size-1 are filled (and allocated) exactly once.

The MATLAB Side of this is simple

```
FinalCellArray = MexCellArrayTest();
```

The issue observed is as follows

- If we remove the definition of IS_CONTIG and allow for contiguous allocation of memory, 
  The Execution is ligntning fast (output < 1ms).
- However, in the other case, with non-contiguous The Output portion (as detected by the 
  profiling code) takes nearly 6 seconds.
- Note that the output is given using the mxSetData Function which (in principle) should
  only copy the address of the memory location as passed to it by IntArrayofArrays[i].

  WHY THE BIG DIFFERENCE?

Comment: Well, I'm confused.  `mxSetData(...)` is definitely the hotspot, but I can't see why.  There is no re-allocation going on, but there is a consistent 1-2 ms delay for each call to `mxSetData`.  There is clearly something else going on under the hood.  Perhaps this is merely an effect of the cache-friendliness when the buffers are taken i order (presumably close/frequently adjacent in memory)

Comment: But The Question remains as to what eactly are those buffers and why does MATLAB seem to need any kind of buffers at all for just copying a pointer.

Comment: I thought maybe it checked to make sure there were in order or aligned or something (despite all documentation indicating otherwise), but the pointers don't change ( no realloc).  And yes, it should just be copying a pointer.  I'm guessing there's some other data check going on.